# The system is running in low graphics mode error on dell inspiron.1525

Tags: graphics, dell, inspiron

How to fix “The system is running in low graphics mode” error on dell inspiron.1525?

Answer (score 2):

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while during the screen shows running in low-graphics mode.
- Login with your username and password
- Then run the below commands,

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  sudo shutdown -r now
  ```

After reboot,you will get back to your default GUI.

Comment: I personally spent many moons on this `silly` stuff a while back.  It seemed so unintuitive to me to just delete the xorg.conf file altogether.  Seeing as in there are so many posts online regarding its configuration.  Its a tough problem as if you really fudge up the file, often you can't login in without going into recovery mode, remounting the hard disk as root with r/w, and then edit/delete xorg.conf.  That is unless you have ssh configured.

Comment: Thank you, but this method did not work .Look for this message
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/x11/xorg.conf’: no such fille or directory

Comment: Then see the link posted by @braiam.